# Return Json sometimes cause problems . .

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have mvc application which through ajax is calling one method and as response I'm getting JSON.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetLines([FromBody]Request request)
    {
        var lines= await Get(request.Name);


        var something = lines.GroupBy(x => new {Month = x.NoOfMonth})
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Month = s.Key.Month,
                Items = s.Select(x=> new {Item = x.Item, Qnt = x.Quantity}).ToList(),
                Target = s.Select(x=>x.Target).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();


        return Json(something);
    }
```

This is code which is returning JSON. So on some records from table it works without any any kind of problem. But for some records I'm getting next error.
Can anyone help me to understand why ? 
[image]

Comment: Have you isolated which records are causing the trouble?

Comment: At the moment no,but it is very strange. for FK which has 20 records it is displaying data normally but for FK which has 20+ it gives me an error. All records are correctly saved in database. Example: Table 1 has id and name. Table 2 has id,fk_table1, qnty,item,target.

Comment: Might you please Please [edit] your question to include your error as **text** rather than as a screen shot, ideally with the entire exception type, message, traceback and inner exception?  On stackoverflow we ask that you include your code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting error, that I saw that my data are not displayed, and I was checking and then I saw that info. It would be much more easier for me if I got an error...

Comment: For this error, it seems to be related with `Mvc.Formatters`. I suggest you put a breakpoint on `var something` and check the list.  Is there any strange value for `Items`? For one option, try to replace anonymouse type with model, define a model with `Month`, `Items` and `Target`.

Comment: I had investigate and problem is present here Items = s.Select(x=> new {Item = x.Item, Qnt = x.Quantity}).ToList() . But when I put ToArray instead of ToList I got data on screen, but in debug still see same info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figure out what was the problem.

> Items = s.Select(x=> new {Item = x.Item, Qnt = x.Quantity}).ToList()
>   Item = x.Item is returning the new list and this were making reference loop, so I had do modification to return single Item what is exactly purpose to return it.

Thanks to every one on spending time to resolve this.